# How do I make the outer and inner donut charts a full circle if their value are not the same?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to have two donut charts in one visual where the outer and inner represent a different year and both are a full circle. The outer or inner donut does not make a full circle if the outer and inner donut does not add up to the same number. I tried to use some transforms outside the layer, but that did not work. I think the problem is outside the layer properties, but I am not sure where to get started.

[image: Double donut]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "3/2/2020", "brand": "Hair", "mentions": 1463},
      {"date": "8/19/2020", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 1912},
      {"date": "10/14/2020", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 6804},
      {"date": "5/7/2020", "brand": "Makeup", "mentions": 4264},
      {"date": "5/7/2021", "brand": "Makeup", "mentions": 4264},
      {"date": "8/4/2021", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 9007}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "mentions",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true,
      "aggregate": "sum"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius2": 100, "radius": 140},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2020}}],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "brand",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": "category"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120, "color": "white"},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2020}}],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "mentions",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "detail": {"field": "brand", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
     {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius2": 150, "radius": 190},
       "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2021}}],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "brand",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": "category"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 170, "color": "white"},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2021}}],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "mentions",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "detail": {"field": "brand", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the config `resolve` for `theta` seems to resolve your issue. It is probably using shared encoding so that might causing the calculation error.

Below is the modified code and [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAZgIAmWwAYb9xSCYAnJLOUWAEkhpuLghwspjssgaoAIwALABslgC+CiZq5ugAHARRAJwOTi7unt7oAGIeZB6yUOZKwaHhkblRNsmpZhZR9tkx+c5KRV4W5UiVnjVBIWFykXEZ9jFtKmkWYgQA7H2FVSUgALJIANZwDDiTDTNoMTZxiynLHehrm042UdvFFgfHp+fTEVcbnd2ukQFleq93gMdsMKlUJnUpo00Dl7PZ1okALrJEAhKBsZQ0WRkNCgehwdSkkAAMxocEEu3q-wMSkwAE8cKCAI4MTxhdRhUguCDqKCHNCYNx6JSjSp8R4gCAMBAgRI4wRINlwQKoYwgZBucWaEDszkWJBuKAuDyEhgQGxoLr2JQ2mh2x0xew4yWeCDUthuFW60C0wRmHUhukMiymWommjBACqsjoFi1FpccB5OjQry9WKUeIJRJJxvxggDVNp9N2g28rI5oNkbAQRJzSmgOnSoCqZFBUDSZADbNVaqWBqNZMbFjMAA9MNakLamk4lOXK+gAO4wESq1lVP0BoN60PhqtR3axlxhJMphfodOBQvZwS5xz5zGF6rF4lUuf3yMawsJlkQbM10GzBoBRoIUZTIOUKAVJUVRxZQKX8V9jWraN0Dra9p3QZtW1kHMx3uCc-wIkALStF0lzde1HTEZ0QFdd1olRb0D39QMjEjMNtXPID0CvVkEzgZNUwfOAM2fXlMMhNVP1xb9CV-Ms2ArCMaQvCw8LApsWzbV8OwHQRu1Yzw+wsAczCHNwRzHccLUnE0qP-Rdl0ddYWPXHUQG3XcuN9Hjj34s8sN0kSVjE28pJAR9MxfN83iUr98TU0syTgechJw-UkUuAyLEg-k1BguNZTceVQWQvcVHQmhMMA-L9Lc8CQCI4zRwLVj9E0oVjU7cy-3gSl0CJNDOS8KZRyUYg6U3KkRTcNhjjQWQGEEQQ1SAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "3/2/2020", "brand": "Hair", "mentions": 1463},
      {"date": "8/19/2020", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 1912},
      {"date": "10/14/2020", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 6804},
      {"date": "5/7/2020", "brand": "Makeup", "mentions": 4264},
      {"date": "5/7/2021", "brand": "Makeup", "mentions": 4264},
      {"date": "8/4/2021", "brand": "Fragrance", "mentions": 9007}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "mentions",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true,
      "aggregate": "sum"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius2": 100, "radius": 140},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2020}}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "brand",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": "category"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120, "color": "white"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2020}}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "mentions",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "detail": {"field": "brand", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius2": 150, "radius": 190},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2021}}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "brand",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": "category"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 170, "color": "white"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "equal": 2021}}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "mentions",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "detail": {"field": "brand", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"theta": "independent"}},
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```